# Checksum comparison file too large

Tags: rsync, hashsum, checksum, synology

I am trying to run a checksum comparison task on a large folder that I `rsync` from one Synology server to another.

What I am trying to get is an output that shows me any differences between the current folder and and how the folder was the last time `rsync` ran - i.e. any files that have been deleted, added, or changed.

But the output I get is way too big - it seems to be including every file in the folder! (It is a 14 MB file of just file names - the actual content folder that rsync is being run on is 6 TB).

Here is the `rsync` task:

```
/usr/bin/rsync -ac --log-file="/volume1/NAS/backup_logs/logs/log.$(date +%Y%m%d%H%m%S).txt" --delete --times --sparse -e "ssh -p {port number}"  /volume1/source_folder username@my.server:/volume1/destination_folder
```

After `rsync` runs, I generate a checksum file:

```
find /volume1/source_folder -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum > /volume1/NAS/checksums/checksums_backup.$(date +%Y%m%d).txt
```

Then I compare the checksum file to the previous one (this will not work the first time):

```
grep -Fxvf /volume1/NAS/checksums/checksums_backup.$(date +%Y%m%d).txt /volume1/NAS/checksums/yesterdays_checksums.txt > /volume1/homes/username/checksums/updated_files.txt
```

And then I copy the checksum as the previous checksum:

```
cp /volume1/NAS/checksums/checksums_backup.$(date +%Y%m%d).txt /volume1/NAS/checksums/yesterdays_checksums.txt
```

But like I said, updated_files.txt ends up being WAY too big, even on the third run. What am I doing wrong?

If there is another simpler way to compare these folders and generate output of differences, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: "_What I'm trying to get is an output that shows me any differences between the current folder and and how the folder was the last time rsync ran_" what's wrong with the output from `rsync -iav /source user@remote:/destination`? Oh, and remove that `-c` from `rsync`; unless you really know you need it, you almost certainly don't.

Comment: Your grep will not show new files. Typically, one keeps sorted lists and can then compare them with `comm`. The result would be more readable if the sums followed the filename, but that's a detail.